# Qt jom.exe error 2

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, windows-10

I have a problem building my project on Windows 10. On my Windows 7 system i use Qt 5.4, msvc2013 and everything works fine. But on my Windows 10 system I cant build my project. Everytime jom.exe throws error 2. I've tried Qt 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6 beta with msvc2013, msvc2012 and even msvc2015. The compile output is always the same.

> 13:02:03: Running steps for project test...
>   13:02:03: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>   13:02:03: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
>       C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
>       cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -W0 -GR -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I. -I..\opencv249\opencv\build\include -I..\3rdparty\api\include -I..\3rdparty\devlibs${PLATFORM}\libusb/include -I..\3rdparty\devlibs${PLATFORM}\devicemanager\include -I....\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include -I....\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtSvg -I....\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -I....\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -I....\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -I....\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtXml -I....\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -I....\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\lineitem.obj.3728.47.jom
>   jom: C:\dev\LOCAL_WORKING_TRUNK\Makefile.Release [release\lineitem.obj] Error 2
>   jom: C:\dev\LOCAL_WORKING_TRUNK\Makefile [release] Error 2
>   13:02:04: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project iQ_afbox (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2015 64bit)
>   When executing step "Make"
>   13:02:04: Elapsed time: 00:00.

PATH look like this

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\dev\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin

What I've overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen if you edit project files by hand that are supposed to be automatically generated (qml.qrc for example). Simply remove all files and add them from Qt Creator GUI again. This should solve your problem. Alternatively you can check the files with an hexadecimal editor to try to spot the problem (a tabulator instead of some spaces, etc.)